# Azure Mobile Services Offline Sync on Existing Project

Tags: ios, azure-mobile-services

I have followed this [article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started-offline-data/) to the letters on the sample app it works fine but in my existing project same code is not doing what it suppose to do. Here's the code:

ParentService:

```
-(MSCoreDataStore *)store{
    if (_store == nil) {
        NSManagedObjectContext * context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

        context.parentContext=[[DataBaseDao sharedDao] managedObjectContext];

        _store = [[MSCoreDataStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:context];
    }
    return _store;
}

-(ParentService *) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialize the Mobile Service client with your URL and key
        self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:kApplicationURL
                                                applicationKey:kApplicationKey];

        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;
        MSCoreDataStore *store = [[MSCoreDataStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:context];

        self.client.syncContext = [[MSSyncContext alloc] initWithDelegate:nil dataSource:store callback:nil];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Here is the code for SearchService that inherits Parent Service:

```
static SearchService *singletonInstance;

+ (SearchService*)getInstance{

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singletonInstance = [[super alloc] init];
    });

    return singletonInstance;
}

-(SearchService *) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _searchTable = [self.client syncTableWithName:@"Search"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In addItem function call to insert occurs with no errors and auto generated id is given with result dictionary and call to syncData occurs but no updates on the server side. Also unable to retrieve data from local store as well. I am unable to verify that record is added to the store or not because .sqlite asks for password.

I have spent several hours on figuring it out but no luck. Odd thing is I am not getting any error which tells me that I might be missing something what that I need to figure out with your help.

Comment: My guess is you didn't initialize the syncContext on your client.  Can you add the client initialization code to your code snippets.

Comment: Thanks, your init isn't using your custom get store, not sure if that would cause your issue.  When you say unable to retrieve from local store, you mean the record isn't in your "Search" table post calling syncTable insert:?  That search was on the same NSManagedObject as you gave the MSSyncContext?

Comment: Oh yeah, if you want to make a workspace, you can use the code and step through to see what may be happening, which just might be faster: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/